# Why does not the readlink show the full path?

Tags: shell, path, readlink

I'm making a shell script to search for files with a specific name and show their full path and size.

For example:

```
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste/1/teste.txt: 14 bytes
```

The code of the segment that I'm having trouble is the next:

```
for i in `find $1 -name $4 -type f -printf "%s "` ; do
    path=`readlink -f $4`
    echo "$path: $i bytes"
done
```

The code returns:

```
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste.txt: 14 bytes
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste.txt: 48 bytes
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste.txt: 29 bytes
```

But should return:

```
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste/1/teste.txt: 14 bytes
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste/2/teste.txt: 48 bytes
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste/teste.txt: 29 bytes
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every iteration of the loop prints argument 4 (`$4`) *of the script*.  That has nothing to do with the results of your `find`.  Perhaps you want something more like this:

```
while read size name; do
    path=`readlink -f $name`
    echo "$path: $size bytes"
done < `find $1 -name $4 -type f -printf '%s %h/%f\n'`
```

Comment: Edited the code to accommodate filenames containing internal spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the size of 3 different files, but only reporting the name of the parameter you pass in.

Try this:

```
( cd -P -- "$1" && find "$(pwd -P)" -name "$4" -type f -printf "$p: %s bytes\n" )
```

- run in a subshell so the cd does not affect the current shell.